# Disable from editing text boxes 1, 2 and 3

Tags: excel, vba

I have an code in listbox2 whereby when you double click on the listbox line it populate all the data from the sheet and be able to edit the data and update however I would like to disable the text boxes 1, 2 and 3 from editing as these boxes the information will never change, I have the code below but so far it is not doing anything with textboxes 1, 2 and 3

```
Private Sub ListBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
'get the records row no
    
    With Me.ListBox2
    
        If IsNull(Me.ListBox2.Value) Then
            MsgBox "Please double click on the name line", vbExclamation, "Select a Name Line"
        Else

        RecordRow = Val(.Column(.ColumnCount - 1, .ListIndex))
    
    
    ControlNames = GetControls(Me)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(ControlNames, 1)
     With sh.Cells(RecordRow, ControlNames(i, 7))
        Me.Controls(ControlNames(i, 1)).Value = .Text
        
            ''''I would like to disable fro editing textboxes 1,2,& 3 once data has been filled''''''
                            Select Case Me.Controls(ControlNames(i, 1))
                                Case 1, 2, 3
                                    .Enabled = False
                                    .BackColor = RGB(155, 295, 155)
                            End Select
                            
        'if text in range does not match text in combobox list you get an error
        If Err <> 0 Then Me.Controls(ControlNames(i, 1)).Value = "": Err.Clear
      End With
    Next i
    
    EnableButtons Me, True
    End If
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```

below it is the control code

```
Function GetControls(ByVal Form As Object) As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Form.Name)
        GetControls = .Range("A2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` this line is evil. It hides **all** your error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see them you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code ccannot work. Remove that line see which errors you get and fix them!

Comment: Please, edit your question and also add the `GetControls` function code. Otherwise, it is difficult to understand what `ControlNames(i, 7)` means. Especially, what does that 7 mean?

Comment: Why don't you just open your userform in the VBA editor and set `Enabled` to `False` for those 3 textboxes? No code needod to disable them. VBA still can add data then. If you still want to do it by code use `Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False`.

Comment: Do you take the controls name from the active sheet? May I know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Dim c As MSForms.Control, arrTbx, mtch
  
  arrTbx = Array("TextBox1", "TextBox2", "TextBox3")
  For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        mtch = Application.match(c.Name, arrTbx, 0)
        If Not IsError(mtch) Then
            c.BackColor = RGB(155, 295, 155)
            c.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
  Next
```

A second version, without iteration, based on @Pᴇʜ's observation:

```
Dim c As MSForms.Control, arrTbx, El 
  
  arrTbx = Array("TextBox1", "TextBox2", "TextBox3")
  For Each El In arrTbx
    On Error Resume Next
        Set c = Me.Controls(El)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.BackColor = RGB(155, 295, 155)
        c.Enabled = False
    Else
        MsgBox El & " text box name does not exist on this form..."
    End If
  Next
```

And your event should look like:

```
Private Sub ListBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim i As Long
    
    With Me.ListBox2
    
        If IsNull(Me.ListBox2.value) Then
            MsgBox "Please double click on the name line", vbExclamation, "Select a Name Line"
        Else

        RecordRow = val(.Column(.ColumnCount - 1, .ListIndex))
        
        'New code___________________________________
        Dim c As MSForms.Control, arrTbx, mtch
  
        arrTbx = Array("TextBox1", "TextBox2", "TextBox3")
        For Each c In Me.Controls
          If TypeOf c Is MSForms.TextBox Then
              mtch = Application.match(c.Name, arrTbx, 0)
              If Not IsError(mtch) Then
                  c.BackColor = RGB(155, 295, 155)
                  c.Enabled = False
              End If
          End If
        Next
        'End new code_________________________________
        
        EnableButtons Me, True 'only you know what is it about...
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Fane it has sort of worked however when i tried to clear the all textboxes on users for a new entry i get an error on one of the command button code at this point   Me.TextBox1.SetFocus

Comment: @Harin Of course, you cannot set focus to a disabled text box. You should reenable it before doing that... Try using ` Me.TextBox1.Enabled = True:  Me.TextBox1.SetFocus`.

Comment: i have tried your new code now textboxes does not poupulate with any data when double click on the listbox and also error comes up on same as before that unable to set focus

Comment: Enablebutton it is in the module of whereby it disable the some commandbuttons and changes it to Clear and Add when boxes are empty

Comment: @Harin Do you know what `Enable = False` means? No offence, but this mean that you cannot use the control in any way! In order to use it, you should use `Enable = True`, and only after that to use it.

Comment: Hi Fane sorry it worked with your previous suggestion and i just done the enabled and change the color for all 3 to vbwhite as it was staying green all the time after deleting the entry

Comment: @Harin Good for you! This is the way. When place a piece of code to do something, you must know how to reverse it, in order to be able to use the control without limitations. And also understand the errors meaning... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru Any reason you loop through **all** controls `For Each c In Me.Controls`? Lets say there are 100 controls you loop through all of them. Why not just looping through the array of `For Each c in arrTbx` and use `Me.Controls(c).Enabled = False` so you loop only through 3 instead of 100?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I thought that the controls name in the array may be wrong and it is necessary to check them. But  you are completely right! I only followed something joined to the brain, when try finding specific controls, of a specific type, but I will adapt/simplify the code to directly use them. With a little error handling, in case the control name from the array does not exist (wrong spelled etc.)...

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Did it. No iteration needed and a message if something wrong in the controls name spelling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping through controls like that and that too for those 3 textboxes, I would recommend this approach

```
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
        Select Case cCont.Name
        '~~> I am assuming that this is the textbox names. 
        '~~> If not, then put the textbox names here
        Case 1, 2, 3 
            .Locked = True
            .BackColor = RGB(155, 295, 155)
        End Select
    End If
Next cCont
```

Also no need to disable them. Simply set the `.Locked` property to `True`. The user will not be able to edit it.

Or better still, make the changes in design time as @Pᴇʜ mentioned in the comments. Simply change the `.Locked` property to `True` in the properties window.

Comment: Hi @Siddharth i have updated my question of where the control code

Comment: I do not need that :) Did you see what I suggested?

Comment: Hi Siddharth i have tried your suggestion and it is not doing anything

Comment: Did you set the locked property to true in design time? or else put the above code in `UserForm_Initialize()`